# How do I route Cloudfront with multiple origins?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

So I have 2 Wordpress sites hosted as such

- `http://siteA.mydomain.com`
- `http://siteB.mydomain.com`

I have a distribution created that has the 2 domains above as the origin.

- `siteA.mydomain.com`
- `siteB.mydomain.com`

I'm not sure how to configure the routes such that 
`http://siteA.mydomain.com/wp-content/*` will go to siteA's domain, and `http://siteB.mydomain.com/wp-content/*` will go to siteB's as the path pattern is the same.

Or should I create another distribution for siteB?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a second distribution.

CloudFront can select the origin server based on path pattern matching **only** -- not the hostname, or other request parameters.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern